# I want scope checkbox checked by default swagger Nswag

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

Here is Swagger/OpenAPI definition:

```
 services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
        {
            document.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>(),
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flow = OpenApiOAuth2Flow.AccessCode,
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"myScope", "myScope"}},
                    AuthorizationUrl = "redacted",
                    TokenUrl = "redacted"
                }));
        });
```

and Swagger-UI configuration options:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
        {
            settings.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
            {
                ClientId = "MyClientID",
                ClientSecret = string.Empty,
                AppName = "My App",
                UsePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant = true
            };
        });
```

I want that scope should be checked by default, Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No sir. there is some suggestion to write some JS around it

Comment: @claudekennilol, here is a workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60960871/968003. Looks ugly, but I haven't seen a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in version 6.0 by `OAuthScopes` method.

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/7740